# Subversion Commit hangs indefinitely after first file

Tags: linux, svn, commit

I'm logged into our Linux web server via SSH. There are only three modifided files in my SVN repository, and I've typed `svn ci -m "message"` to commit them. I've been committing files all morning without any trouble, but now svn is hanging trying to send the first file!

My screen currently looks like this:

```
Sending        path/to/my/file.php



^C



^C





.
```

This `^C` of course is where, after several minutes of waiting, I tried to cancel the operation using Control-C. The blank lines are where I pressed Enter just to make sure my SSH connection was still active.

I logged in again and performed an `svn status` on the repo, and it shows that everything's locked.

What's going on here?? What can I do to rescue my repo and get it to commit normally again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the exact same symptom, and in my case it turned out to be an RPC lock issue. I access my repo using file: locally and over NFS, and via svn+ssh:.

I couldn't commit from any client, but everything else worked fine.

Apparently an NFS client got out of whack and left a lock on the repo.  ( Probably my MacBook using WIFI, which has proven to be an unreliable NFS client in general. )

Restarting statd and lockd on the server housing the repo immediately resolved the issue.

Comment: I never did determine what process was holding onto the repo, but restarting the server (and doing a cleanup) seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess - and this is a complete WAG - you are using a [Berkeley DB backed repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends.bdb) and are accessing the repo via file:// or svn+ssh://.

The best practice for using a BDB backed repo is to only access via svnserve (svn://) or the apache dav_svn module (http://) - this helps eliminate several issues around file ownership for the database log files.  If you need to run a BDB repo, and you need to access via svn+ssh:// or file://, you should review the [Supporting Multiple Repository Access Methods](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html) section of the Version Control with Subversion book.

If you aren't particularly tied to a BDB repo, I'd take a look at FSFS repos.  They don't have many of the issues that the BDB repos have.

If you are already running an FSFS repo... well, you've got me there.  I didn't think it was possible to wedge a FSFS repo.